# Unable to use Ajax beforeSend and complete functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, spinner

I am trying to load the spinner image during ajax data loading hower none of my codes seem to work. Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Observer/GetInfoProfileByProfileId',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    ProfileId: profileId,
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    console.log('spinner shown');
    $('#spinner').css('display', 'block');
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('spinner hidden');
    $('#spinner').css('display', 'none');
  },
  success: function(response) {

    //..do something with response
  }
});
```

What is wrong with the codes above ? Appreciate any help

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Could it be that the request completes so fast that you actually do not get enough time to see the spinner ?  Also are you sure the spinner would be inside the screen when its `display` is set to `block` ?

Comment: Yes i styled the spinner to be inside the screen because i can see it when i manually change its display property in the inspector.

Comment: Seems to work at https://jsfiddle.net/ocu1nm4k/
What jquery version are you using ?

Comment: *(and also make sure there are no errors thrown inside the `success` callback as that would make the `complete` not to get called)*

Comment: I am using the version 1.9.1

Comment: @Xris if the problem persists after checking the above comments, please post a live version with the problem because as it is, it is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, the issue i misspelled the name of my id in the html